.NET MongoDB.Driver 3.0.0 no longer has MongoClientSettings.LinqProvider
After upgrading to MongoDB.Driver 3.0.0, MongoClientSettings no longer contains the LinqProvider property.
Where has this moved to?  I need it for my Mongo client to be able to talk to different MongoDB serve versions.

According to the upgrade guide for v3, this version drops support for MongoDB server versions below 4.0, and removes version 2 of the Linq provider. Therefore, there is no option to change the provider.
